# Can a 501c7 have a fundraiser by selling handmade crafts?

Tags: united-states, income, tax-exemption, non-profit

We are a 501c7 mutual benefit social club of knitters. We all pay dues to cover rent, etc for our leased space. Can we contribute handmade crafts to sell to the public as a fundraising activity?